# Потокобезопасное чтение boolean-переменной delphi

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Основной поток создает множество доп. потоков. Есть несколько ***флагов-переменных*** с типом **boolean**. Общение между потоками происходит через критические секции, но простое чтение ***флаг-переменной*** это же атомарная операция и для нее не нужна критическая секция?

Comment: Чтение и запись - да, в данном случае атомарны. Главное, чтобы запись не зависела от чтения. К примеру - читаем > вклинивается другой поток и записывает свое > записываем. Если такое развитие событий нежелательно - нужно экранировать.

Comment: а запись в boolean не атомарная операция?

Comment: Атомарная. Но обратите внимание на последовательность: поток 1 читает и анализирует переменную со значением True -> в это время поток 2 проводит свои манипуляции и записывает в нее False -> управление возвращается в поток 1 и он решает, что переменная должна быть True. Всё, значение, записанное потоком 2 пропало. А может быть и другая последовательность: поток 1 читает True->поток 2 читает True->поток 1 записывает False->поток 2 записывает True. Если это важно - нужно экранировать. Если не важно - можно игнорить.

Comment: @kami тут вопрос чисто про чтение. так что КС не нужны, да.

Comment: Операция атомарная, но есть aba problem

Comment: @Kromster опубликовал, но у меня есть смутное подозрение, что это уже было, причем - не раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтение (именно чтение) из переменной типа `Boolean` (`Byte`, `Word`, `DWORD`, `Integer`, `Cardinal`, `Native[U]Int`) - действительно атомарная операция и для нее не нужно использовать методы синхронизации потоков.

Однако, существует так называемая [ABA-проблема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_ABA), упомянутая в комментарии @Vasek . Если вкратце - пока один поток считал значение и работает в предположении, что оно "вот такое", другой поток может поменять его. А когда первый поток результат своей работы решит записать в эту переменную - значение, присвоенное вторым потоком пропадет.

В случае, если несколько потоков могут записывать в эту переменную и при этом последовательность действий зависит от содержимого переменной - то работу можно и нужно экранировать.

Одним из лучших вариантов (на мой взгляд) в этом плане будет применение [TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer) , который позволяет учитывать "блокировку при работе на чтение" и "блокировку при работе на запись". Применение этого класса вместо `TCriticalSection`, `TMutex` или `TEvent` во многих случаях позволит сократить непроизводительный простой потоков.

Comment: С точки зрения производительности, в данном случае, по-моему, будет лучше использовать [Interlocked WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122(v=vs.85).aspx).